# How to sort own set that based on linkedList without any standard java libraries?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, linked-list

*I created set based on LinkedList and want to sort the nodes, whan i add value to the set, ho can I do that without any standard java libraries?*
    package ru.matevosyan;

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * DynamicSetByLinkedListclass.
```

* Created on 29.05.2017.
 * @author Matevosyan Vardan
 * @version 1.0
 */

```
public class DynamicSetByLinkedList<E> implements IDynamicSetByLinkedList<E>, Iterable<E> {

    private Node<E> last;
    private int size = 0;
    private Node<E> first;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */

    public DynamicSetByLinkedList() {

    }

    /**
     * Create to add value to the set.
     * @param value is value that type which you declare in generics.
     */

    @Override
    public void add(E value) {
        if (!checkDuplicate(value)) {
            linkLast(value);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDuplicate(E value) {
        Node<E> firstNode = first;
        boolean hasDuplicate = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < size & size > 1; i++) {
            firstNode = firstNode.next;
            if (firstNode == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (firstNode.item.equals(value)) {
                hasDuplicate = true;
            }
        }
        return hasDuplicate;
    }

    /**
     * linkLast assign LinkedList Node to the last Node in the list and if it is the first value assign as first too.
     * @param elementValue is value.
     */

    private void linkLast(E elementValue) {
        Node<E> lastNode = last;
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(lastNode, elementValue, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (lastNode != null) {
            lastNode.next = newNode;
        } else {
            first = newNode;
        }
        size++;

        if(size > 1) {
            sortByHashcode();
        }
    }

    private void sortByHashcode() {


**here going to be a sort algorithm**
        }
    }

    /**
     * For returning the size of set.
     * @return size
     */

    public int len() {
        return size;
    }
    /**
     * Class Node describe linkedList entry.
     * @param <E> parameter that defined when create an instance of a class.
     */

    private static class Node<E> {
        E item;
        Node<E> prev;
        Node<E> next;

        Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
            this.prev = prev;
            this.item = element;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override iterator method from interface Iterable.
     * @return an instance of Iterator type.
     */

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {

        return new Iterator<E>() {

            int count = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return (count < size) && (last != null);
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                count++;
                Node<E> nextNode = first;

                if (nextNode != null && count > 1) {
                    nextNode = nextNode.next;
                }

                if (nextNode == null | size < count) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("Does not exist");
                }
                return nextNode.item;

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: [You can choose any algorithm and implement it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: For what purposes do you want to write your own sort method? Just for learning?

Comment: yes, I don't imagine how to sort nodes in my own collection code

Comment: I know how sort ArrayList but i want to know how do it with linkedList

Comment: You can use virtually any algorithm for sorting LinkedList. Can you show your sort method or say what the problems you have encountered.

Comment: Wiki article includes the logic for [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists), using a small (25 to 32) array of pointers to nodes to hold internal lists. For java, this would be a small array of references to nodes. This is the fastest linked list sort, but it would be faster still to generate an array of references to every node, and then use an array oriented sort, then relink the sorted nodes.

Comment: For example I want to sort with bubble sort, how I can do it with linkedList?

Comment: I looked at your code once again, and I think that I've caught your problem. You do not need a sort algorithm. I'll post a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your collection is going to be already sorted after each `add()` method you need to find the place of a new element in the list. Look, when you add the first element your collection is definitely sorted, so adding next elements you just need to find their particular place. So you can use the next implementation for this:

```
private void sortByHashcode() {
    Node<E> node = first;

    while (node != null) {
        if (last.item.hashCode() < node.item.hashCode()) {
            Node<E> tmp = last.prev;
            last.next = node;
            last.prev = node.prev;
            node.prev = last;
            if (last.prev == null) {
                first = last;
            } else {
                last.prev.next = last;
            }
            tmp.next = null;
            last = tmp;
            break;
        }

        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

P.S. However, in my opinion, it's a quite weird collection. I think you should think again and you can use one of standard Java collections(i.e. TreeSet with your comparator). Can you explain what the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how this line work - last.prev.next = last, What this line do?

Comment: Well, if it's not the first node `last.prev != null` then we put the last element into a new position and need to restore the chain of the elements -  `last.prev.next = last` changes link to the previous element of the last element which is now placed in the new position. I would recommend you to draw the mechanism of LinkedList work or [you can watch it](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=linkedlist)

Comment: Since you might be able to understand Russian you can read [this useful article](https://habrahabr.ru/post/127864/). If you have questions won't hesitate to ask them.

Comment: Thanks, I already do it by myself, if you want, you can go to the [Java Для программиста](https://vk.com/club128029291?z=photo-128029291_456239022%2Falbum-128029291_00%2Frev) . It is my group in vk.com, I often forget important thing I taught.

Comment: Well, I don't use vk.com, but thanks for your offer. I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as correct. BTW [this is the JR group in skype](https://join.skype.com/fMmcOQ1ZLUYI)

Answer (score 0):

If the linked list contains primitive types you can sort using :

```
Collections.sort(list,null);
```

In case the linked list contains an object of a class you created then you should implements a Comporator to do your own comparaison logic

Comment: Collections in Java can't contain primitive types.

Comment: I meant Wrapper classes

Comment: I think the OP would like some sorting without "standard java library", so `Collections.sort` will probably not help here.

Comment: notice that i want to sort without any standard java libraries, only by my hand/

Comment: I think you should use arrays and implement the sorting logic using a sorting algorithm